# Microsoft Teams Direct/Group Chat Messages Retrieval

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, bad-request, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been using "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/{id}/messages" this Ms-Graph API to retrieve the Chat Messages for (Direct/Group Chat) in Microsoft Teams.  I get first set of response (i.e. 20 Messages) but when i try to get the next set of messages using the "@odata.nextLink" property i encountered "Bad Request" error.

Is there any other way to retrieve the Next set of Chat Messages from Group/Direct Chat in Microsoft Teams?

Comment: I am not quite sure but  I suspect Graph API you are using is Beta and hence the issue.
When you mean Group Chat, do you mean [Group Conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get-conversation?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)?

Comment: We are checking this error it internally. 
The workaround for this is - use [query parameter.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta#top-parameter). This will get you top number of results

Answer (score 1):

Please use the [query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters)  $skip in conjunction with $top to have finer control over the result if nextLink is not working ( could be because it's still in Beta).
For example, use the below query to get 30 entries  after skipping 30 entries

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/{id}/messages?$top=30&$skip=30
```